Flutter : Nested showModalBottomSheet not refresh the Ui after SaveAddress and call setState
If you see my code i have a two showModalBottomSheet first one in address list where i load address using future builder and second is inside this one more showModalBottomSheet where i select and save address when i save address is not rebuild the and refresh the first one address list showModalBottomSheet ui.
When i reopen again then show new address, I want to need after new address saved refresh ui.
Anyone one can you please help on this i am stuck on last 2 days.
Future _buildSelectAddress() {
int? selectedIndex;
return showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  useSafeArea: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
        return Container(
          height: 500,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const Text('Saved address',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              TextButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    housenumber.text = "";
                    landmark.text = "";
                    _isButtonDisabled = true;
                  });
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    isScrollControlled: true,
                    useSafeArea: true,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return StatefulBuilder(
                        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                          return Stack(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 530,
                                child: PlacePicker(
                                  apiKey: "myapi key-DUYSt92Ll2mMSFt****************",
                                  onPlacePicked: (PickResult result) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      addressData['address'] =
                                          result.formattedAddress ?? "";
                                    });
                                  },
                                  desiredLocationAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
                                  hintText: "Find a place ...",
                                  searchingText: "Please wait ...",
                                  selectText: "NEXT",
                                  initialPosition: _center,
                                  useCurrentLocation: false,
                                  enableMapTypeButton: false,
                                  selectInitialPosition: true,
                                  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
                                  enableMyLocationButton: true,
                                  selectedPlaceWidgetBuilder: (_,
                                      selectedPlace, state,
                                      isSearchBarFocused) {
                                    Future<void> updateAddress() async {
                                      if (selectedPlace != null)
                                      {addressData['address'] = selectedPlace?.formattedAddress;
                                        addressData['latitude'] = selectedPlace?.geometry?.location.lat.toDouble();
                                        addressData['longitude'] = selectedPlace?.geometry?.location.lng.toDouble();

                                        List<Placemark> addresses = await
                                        placemarkFromCoordinates(addressData['latitude'], addressData['longitude']);
                                        Placemark data = addresses.first;

                                        addressData['city'] = data.locality;
                                        addressData['area'] = data.subLocality;
                                        addressData['pincode'] = data.postalCode;
                                        setState(() {});
                                      }
                                    }

                                    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                                      updateAddress();
                                    });
                                    return isSearchBarFocused
                                        ? Container()
                                        : FloatingCard(
                                      bottomPosition: 0.0,
                                      leftPosition: 0.0,
                                      rightPosition: 0.0,
                                      width: 500,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                      child: state == SearchingState.Searching ? const Center(child: Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                      ))
                                          : Container(),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              _build_addressfields(),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                label: Text('Add another address'),
              ),
              Divider(),
              FutureBuilder(
                future: DioProvider().getCustomeraddress(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                      return const Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text('Address not found.'),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            var address = snapshot.data?[index];
                            return ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              leading: Radio(
                                value: address['id'],
                                groupValue: selectedIndex,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedIndex = value;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              title: Text('${address['address_type']}'),
                              subtitle: Text('${address['address']}',
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  maxLines: 2),
                              trailing: PopupMenuButton<String>(
                                onSelected: (String value) {
                                  if (value == 'Edit') {
                                    // Handle edit action
                                  } else if (value == 'Delete') {
                                    // Handle delete action
                                  }
                                },
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                                  const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: 'Edit',
                                    child: Text('Edit'),
                                  ),
                                  const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: 'Delete',
                                    child: Text('Delete'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                // Handle address tap action
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const Text('Something went wrong, Please try again after some time');
                  }
                  return const Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Proceed'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 36),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);

}
This is my Address select field and saved the address
Widget _build_addressfields() {
 return DraggableScrollableSheet(
  builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
    if(housenumber == ""){
      setState(() {
        _isButtonDisabled = true;
      });
    }
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
      return Container(
        height: 400,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: scrollController,
          itemCount: 1,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Text(addressData['address']),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _isButtonDisabled = value.isEmpty;
                      });
                    },
                    controller: housenumber,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                      labelText: 'Flat/House Number*',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: landmark,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                      labelText: 'Landmark (Optional)',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade200),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CustomRadioButton("Home", selectedValue, handleChange),
                    CustomRadioButton("Office", selectedValue, handleChange),
                    CustomRadioButton("Other", selectedValue, handleChange),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: _isButtonDisabled
                        ? () {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Please fill the Flat/House Number field.'),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    : () async {
                      addressData['house_flatno'] = housenumber.text;
                      addressData['landmark'] = landmark.text;
                      addressData['address_type'] = selectedValue;
                      try {
                        var save = await DioProvider().saveCustomerAddress(addressData);
                        if(save['statucode'] == 200){
                          setState(() {});
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        }else{
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              SnackBar(
                                behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                                duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
                                content: Text('${save['error']}'),
                                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                              ));
                        }
                      }catch(e){
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(
                              behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                              duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                              content: Text('Server Error: Somthing went wrong, try again after some time'),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                            ));
                        }
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        elevation: 0,
                        backgroundColor: _isButtonDisabled ? Colors.grey : Colors.redAccent,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text('Save & Proceed'),
                    ),
                  ),

                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      );
      },
    );
  },
  initialChildSize: 0.4,
  minChildSize: 0.25,
  maxChildSize: 0.45,
);

}
